How to visualize a complex Bifactor SEM with Third-order Factor?
I'm working on visualizing a complex bifactor Structural Equation Modeling (SEM) in R with a third-order factor (AUTOREGULACION) and several nested factors.
I've run into issues with  layout when trying to represent the model graphically using semPlot(). The model includes first-order factors (F1 to F11), second-order factors (PLANIFICACION, EJECUCION, AUTOEVALUACION), and a third-order factor that encompasses the second-order factors. Here's the lavaan package syntax for my model:
model_AF <- '
  # First Order Factors
  F1 =~ P3 + P4 + P9 + P10 + P13 + P14 + P15 + P20
  F2 =~ P6 + P8 + P11 + P12 + P16 + P17 + P18 + P19 + P22 + P26
  F3 =~ P1 + P2 + P5 + P7
  F4 =~ P21 + P23 + P24 + P25
  F5 =~ P27 + P28 + P29 + P30 + P31 + P33 + P40
  F6 =~ P34 + P37 + P39 + P41 + P43
  F7 =~ P36 + P38 + P42 + P44
  F8 =~ P32 + P35
  F9 =~ P50 + P51 + P52 + P53 + P54 + P55 + P56 + P57 + P58 + P58 + P59
  F10 =~ P45 + P46 + P47 + P48 + P49 + P61
  F11 =~ P60 + P62

  # Second Order Factors
  PLANIFICACION =~ 1*F1 + 1*F2 + 1*F3 + 1*F4
  EJECUCION =~ 1*F5 + 1*F6 + 1*F7 + 1*F8
  AUTOEVALUACION =~ 1*F9 + 1*F10 + 1*F11

  # Third Order Factor
  AUTOREGULACION =~ 1*PLANIFICACION + 1*EJECUCION + 1*AUTOEVALUACION
  AUTOREGULACION ~~ AUTOREGULACION
'

model_fit <- cfa(model_AF, data = base, orthogonal = FALSE)
semPaths(model_fit, whatLabels="est", layout="tree", rotation=2)

After fitting the model, I attempted to visualize it using semPlot::semPaths() with various layout and rotation options. But the result can only be seen up to the second order. When trying to use the third one, the diagram becomes disordered and loses structure.
2 order:

3 order:

What are the best practices for visualizing such a complex SEM?
Are there specific semPlot parameters or other R packages that could handle this level of complexity better?
I hope you can help me

The reason why the third order factors are not displayed properly is because of the layout used. Using the "tree2" layout, the algorithm manages to sort it much better without so much code, although there are still many details to be fine-tuned due to the number of factors and items.
semPaths(model_fit, 
         whatLabels = "std", 
         layout = "tree2",  
         rotation = 2, 
         sizeMan = 2.5, 
         sizeMan2 = 1,
         sizeLat = 4, 
         residuals = FALSE, 
         edge.label.cex = 0.5, 
         edge.color = "black", 
         intercepts = FALSE,  
         thresholds = FALSE, 
         label.cex = 1.2,
         mar = c(0.5, 3, 0.5, 3)) 


There are some other ways to be more precise in the manipulation of the generated plots, especially in the layout, either from semPlot itself or from other packages such as semptools and tidySEM.
